# Passing information from a TableViewController to a DetailViewController

Tags: ios, tableview, segue

I am having issues passing information to the `DetailViewController`. I am able to populate my table view without any issues and able to go to the detail view, but in the detail view the information is not displaying. it just remains blank.

I have my list of data in my table view, with a Name, Category and Date label, and when I pass it to the detail view, I want it to remain the same.

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: For your future programming life, please take a deep look at the naming convention by google: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml

Comment: ok, thank you. but this doesn't help me resolve why it doesn't pass the information correctly right?

Comment: I think it might help, u try to reach _Name (for example) but maybe u can't reach it... Underscore is for internal usage (by convention). Can u add the entire code of DetailViewController?

Comment: What is exactly _DetailModal ?

Comment: I have update the question with the entire code of DetailViewController. Maybe if I send you the entire project it could be easier for you to understand?

_DetailModal comes from my DetailViewController.h: 
`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *DetailModal;` @gran33

Comment: Try moving the code from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear

Comment: i added 
`-(void)viewWillAppear
{
    _NameLabel.text = _DetailModal[0];
    _CategoryLabel.text = _DetailModal[1];
    _DateLabel.text = _DetailModal[2];
    
     self.navigationItem.title = _DetailModal[0];  
}`

but now when i open the detailview, instead of having the labels empty, they just say "label". The name of the detailview however still doesn't appear..

Comment: Can you add the .h file as well?

Comment: @gran33, I added my entire code for the table view

Comment: Try to access each param self.Name (for example), Don't access them with _Name. This might solve your problem (if so, great, otherwise, comment again).

Comment: I changed them all from _Name to self.Name, _Date to self.Date, _Category to self.Category but still no luck. it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you debug the value of myIndexPath? Is it as u expect?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45059/discussion-between-dcb-and-gran33)

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again, but i was thinking, is there a way to order the data in my tableview according to name/date/category? I mean, is it possible to implement a button to make it order the list by name/date/category? Or do i have to use NSMutableArray.. @gran33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your segue has the same name: `ShowDetails` in storyboard as written at the if statement ;)